# Find all negative real values of $x$ such that $x^{x^x}$ is real?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponential-function, real-numbers

> Find all negative real values of $x$ such that $x^{x^x}$ is real?

I know that if $a<0$, $a^b$ is real if and only if $b$ can be written as $b=\frac pq$ where $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd (p,q)=1$ and $q$ is odd.

So $x^x=\frac pq$ (with $\gcd (p,q)=1$ and $q$ is odd) because $x^{x^x}$ is real.
Similarly $x=\frac rl$ (with $\gcd (r,l)=1$ and $l$ is odd) because $x^x$ is real.
This simplifies to $\left(\frac rl\right)^\frac rl=\frac pq~~~~~~~(1)$

It seems to me  the above equation is satisfied only if $\frac rl$ is an odd integer. I am able to prove that it is true if $\frac rl$ is odd but not able to prove that it is true only if $\frac rl$ is true. Can someone help me in proving that the only solutions for $x$ are negative odd integers or can someone give an example(s) for other solutions?

Comment: Hint.  If $x < 0$ so if if $x = \frac rl$ then $\frac rl < 0$ so $(\frac rl)^{\frac rl} = (\frac lr)^{|\frac rl|} = -\frac {|l|^{|\frac rl|}}{|r|^{|\frac rl|}} = -\frac {\sqrt_l{|l|}^{|r|}} {\sqrt_l{|r|}^{|r|}}$.  We need that to be rational so what can we say about $\sqrt_l{|l|}^{|r|$.

Comment: Here's another hint.   If $q$ is a positive integer then $q < 2^q \le c^q$ for all integer $q$.  So $q$ can not be a perfect $q$ power so $\sqrt[q]{q}$ is irrationa.  And if $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ then $(\sqrt[q]{q})^p = q^{\frac pq}$ is irrational.  .. Now consider $x = -\frac pq$ then $x^x = (-\frac pq)^{-\frac pq} = -\frac {q^{\frac pq}}{p^{\frac pq}}$.